# Linking Wordpress page and subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have a site with 1and1. We use Wordpress for the content. I've created a new page called Watch, i.e. www.website.com/watch.

However, I want it as a subdomain - i.e. watch.website.com. I've created the subdomain through 1and1 but I don't know how to link the two?

I also want the address to stay as watch.website.com. I don't want it to redirect back to website.com/watch.

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

If you want TWO sites managed by the same login information, and running off the same DB, you use Multisite. That means you install it ONCE in one place, and make a subsite.

Now. If you HAVE an extant install in that subdomain, it makes it harder.

Go to your main site, the one at domain.com

Turn on Multisite per http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

FOLLOW ALL THE DIRECTIONS. In order. One at a time. There's a point where you have to add ONE line and THEN add more. If you try doing it another way, you'll get messed up.

Make sure that the main site still works.

Make sure you changed your htaccess correctly.

Then add a test site and see how that goes.

If you're using subDOMAIN, make sure you set up wildcards to point where the main domain is installed.

Comment: It all sounds very complicated. Is there another way of just creating a standalone page (ignoring www.website.com/watch and just making a new page watch.website.com)? How would I map that instead?